# How to disable delete button in ASP.NET Dynamic Data?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I need to disable delete button **GLOBALLY** based on some condition?

The following solutions will not work for me:
http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/07/securing-dynamic-data-preview-4-refresh.html
http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/05/dynamicdata-miscellaneous-bits-part-6.html

Again, I do not want to go into every list and detail page and disable it there.

Comment: can you explain this a little more.  ex: Disable all delete buttons throughout app based on role, disable all delete buttons when some event happens, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just extend/inherit from button.  You could make your own button that "knows" how to check if it should be hidden:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public void HiddenCheck()
    {
        bool visible = true;
        //Check to see if the button should be hidden
        this.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```

Then, just use this button instead of the "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button" button wherever you need the delete button functionality.

-Make that "Enabled."  I read the post again, and I guess you aren't trying to "hide" the button, but disable it.  The idea is the same though.